# Unable to find the driver mysql. Register this driver in the Databases tab

Tags: netbeans, wildfly

Que tal buenas tardes estoy tratando de crear una nueva entidad de clases de base de datos conectando con Mysql y como servidor "WildFly 10. final" ya cree el datasource en el servidor y cree la conexión desde netbeans pero no me deja crearlo. Si me pudieran ayudar se les agradece mucho.

[image: Imagen del error en netbeans]

Saludos.

Comment: NetBeans necessita el driver porque no utiliza la conexion de WildFly pero una otra utilzando los parametros del servidor (sorry for my spanish).

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, alquien quien ayude a solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te falta es el driver de `Mysql` lo puedes descargar [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Cuando ya lo tengas para usarlo solo debes de descomprirlo y usar `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar`

Luego buscas en tu proyecto la parte de libraries, buscas el jar en donde lo hayas descomprimido y listo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te quedara algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]